# Can Fredholm integral equation of the first type be represented as a differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Can [Fredholm integral equation of the first type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation#Equation_of_the_first_kind) be represented as a differential equation? In other words, given a Fredholm integral equation of the second type does there exist a differential equation that has the same solution. More practically, is there some kind of transformation that would make this integral equation a differential equation?

Comment: I have wondered the same thing myself. In exercises, you usually differentiate termwise with respect to $t$, and after some struggle some miraculous cancellation erases integrals, leaving you with a solvable Sturm-Liouville boundary value problem. I guess that not all kernels have this property, though.